# difference between '/author' and 'author' in XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I am currently learning XPath query. I feel confuse When I look at these two query '/author' and 'author'. On this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx, 'author' 
 is to find all  elements within the current context and '/author' is to find The document element () of this document. So what's the difference between them. Further, what is 'author/first-name' mean. From the example on the website above, I think it is equal to '//author/firt-name'. Do I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/author` finds `author` in the root. `author` finds `author` in the current node. `//author` finds `author` in *any* node.

Comment: Are /author and anuthor return the same result if I use them query the same document?

Comment: Only if the current node is the root node.

Comment: Is current node the root node if I directly query the document?

Comment: What is "directly query the document" supposed to mean?

Comment: For example, I have a document <x><y><z> red </z></y></x> <y><z>green</z></y>, what's the result of 'y' and 'y/x'?

Comment: It depends on what the current node is.

Comment: OK. How can I know what's the current node is? and how can I define the current node?

Comment: You would have performed previous operations that would change the current node, or you would pass the node of interest to the XML function. If you haven't performed any operations yet then the current node is the root node.